# Page refresh inserts twice

Tags: php

I have a search page that when someone searches it has a query to insert it into my database to keep record of searches, whenever you search it inserts the same row multiple times. Same for my hitcounter script and download counter,

```
include'header.php';
include'db.php';


$d = date("Y-m-d");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO search VALUES('$d','','$ab','1')");
```

Thats the only php code i have on the search page so i dont know why its inserting multiple times per search.

Comment: show us your html code as well

Comment: How do you send a request? Provide client-side code, please.

Answer (score 0):

Redirect to the same page after insert query

```
include'header.php';
include'db.php';

if(isset($_POST)){
    $d = date("Y-m-d");
    mysql_query("INSERT INTO search VALUES('$d','','$ab','1')");

    header('location:page_name.php');
    exit();
}
```